# My banner section is not showing in my static html website, rest is working fine

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to host my static website on firebase everything is working fine except this banner code. All images of my website are working perfectly fine except these banner images and are placed in same folder. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help, many thanks in advance.

```css
.pogoSlider{
    width:100%;
    height:874px!important;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#column-left .pogoSlider,#column-right .pogoSlider,#content .pogoSlider{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.pogoSlider--banner .pogoSlider-slide{
    ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity:1;
}

.pogoSlider-slide{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size:100% 100%;
    -o-background-size:100% 100%;
    -ms-background-size:100% 100%;
    min-height:650px!important;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-perspective:1300px;
    perspective:1300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.pogoSlider-loading{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#eaeaea;
    z-index:11;
}
```

```html
<div class="pogoSlider" id="js-main-slider">
    
    <div class="pogoSlider-slide " data-transition="verticalSlide" data-duration="1000"  style="background-image:url(/public/images/home1.jpg);">
        <div class="pogoSlider-slide-element">
        <h3><span>MOBLIE</span>  Finance</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pogoSlider-slide " data-transition="verticalSlide" data-duration="1000"  style="background-image:url(public/images/home2.jpg);">
        <div class="pogoSlider-slide-element">
        <h3><span>MOBLIE</span>  REPAIRING</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pogoSlider-slide " data-transition="verticalSlide" data-duration="1000"  style="background-image:url(public/images/home3.jpg);">
        <div class="pogoSlider-slide-element">
            <h3>WE <span>SELL</span> MOBILE ACCESSORIES</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pogoSlider-slide " data-transition="verticalSlide" data-duration="1000"  style="background-image:url(public/images/home4.jpg);">
        <div class="pogoSlider-slide-element">
            
            <h3>BEST <span>PRICE</span>. IN AREA</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /banner section -->
```

Comment: Take the following steps: Open dev tool of chrome (F12), Tab network -> img, what is your error (red color)?

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake while uploading js files. It's working fine now but now the problem is, when I open my page for the first time in browser it's not showing the text of first slide, it shows only image but when I refresh it works perfectly fine! Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the actual error but I suspect its your first `.pogoSlider-slide` element, which has a url of `background-image:url(/public/images/home1.jpg)` when I think you don't need that first `/` so `background-image:url(public/images/home1.jpg)`

Comment: I tried your suggestion still, it's not working. I wonder what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `opacity: 0` in `.pogoSlider-slide`. Just remove these 3 lines (mentioned below), banner will show up.

```css
.pogoSlider-slide{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size:100% 100%;
    -o-background-size:100% 100%;
    -ms-background-size:100% 100%;
    min-height:650px!important;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; //***Remove this
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); //***Remove this
    opacity:0; //***Remove this
    -webkit-perspective:1300px;
    perspective:1300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake while uploading js files. It's working fine now but now the problem is, when I open my page for the first time in browser it's not showing the text of first slide, it shows only image but when I refresh it works perfectly fine! Any suggestion please?